# How to determine if the object is on the right or left

Tags: math, lua, scripting, roblox

In roblox studio, i make my game and i should determine if the object is on the right or left relative to the player like this

[image: 1]

Arrow is player the direction the player is looking at

I tried to figure out the location of the part and the player's position, and I figured out the distance between the part and the player, but it didn't help

Comment: Can't dig up Roblox's docs at the moment, but this should theoretically solvable via [Dot Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product). Take the Dot Product of the Part an the player's right direction. If the number is positive, then it's to the Right, if its Negative, then it's to the left.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I solved this problem using vector, next time i'll produce more imformation relate to mathmatic and code, sorry and thanks for watching my problem.